# One-hot encoding using scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I am working on a machine learning project and one feature of my dataset consists of categorical data. This data is first stored in an panda series (`<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`) `mesh` with dimmensions of`(2000,)`. The number of rows corresponds to the total number of data instances. Each row contains a string of the categories to which that data instance belongs to where the categories are separated by a comma. There are several hundred different categories. For example,

```
0       Aged, Angiotensin-Converting Enzyme Inhibitors...
1       Aged, Angiotensin-Converting Enzyme Inhibitors...
2       Adult, Aged, Aged, 80 and over, Angiotensin-Co...
....
```

In this example `Aged` is one category and `Angiotensin-Converting Enzyme Inhibitors` another. As you can see in the example, the same category may occur multiple times but this should encode no differently if the category was only in the string once.

I wish to use one-hot encoding to represent them. To try to do this I use this code:

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)
for s in data:
   pre_data = mlb.fit_transform(str(s).split(', '))
return pre_data, len(mlb.classes_)
```

However, this produces a numpy array of dimensions `(19, 37)`. Why is this the case?

**In response to [MaxU's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741205/maxu) answer:**

When repalcing `str(s).split(', ')` with `s.str.split(',\s*')`, this produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../guidedLearning.py", line 166, in <module>
    X, y = processTrainingData(directory, filename)
  File ".../guidedLearning.py", line 130, in processTrainingData
    pre_mesh, meshN = oneHot(mesh)
  File ".../guidedLearning.py", line 73, in oneHot
    pre_data = mlb.fit_transform(data.str.split(',\s*'))
  File ".../sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 723, in fit_transform
    yt = self._transform(y, class_mapping)
  File ".../sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 781, in _transform
    indices.extend(set(class_mapping[label] for label in labels))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Why not print the mlb.classes_ to see for yourself?

Comment: @VivekKumar See edit

Answer (score 1):

`str(s)` converts Pandas.Series of strings into a single string, delimited by `'\n'`, so use `Pandas.Series.str.split()` method instead.

replace

```
str(s).split(', ')
```

with

```
s.str.split(',\s*')
```

Demo:

```
In [88]: s
Out[88]:
0       Aged, Angiotensin-Converting Enzyme Inhibitors
1       Aged, Angiotensin-Converting Enzyme Inhibitors
2    Adult, Aged, Aged, 80 and over, Angiotensin-Co...
Name: s, dtype: object

In [89]: mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)

In [90]: pre_data = mlb.fit_transform(s.str.split(',\s*'))

In [91]: mlb.classes_
Out[91]: array(['80 and over', 'Adult', 'Aged', 'Angiotensin-Converting Enzyme Inhibitors'], dtype=object)

In [92]: pre_data.toarray()
Out[92]:
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```